# macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: cmake, grep, linker-errors, apple-m1

I use apple m1 clion to test grpc c++ sample demon
CMakeLists.txt as fellow:

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(grpc_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.33.2_1/lib)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
#find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
#if(PROTOBUF_FOUND)
#    message(STATUS "protobuf library found")
#else()
#    message(FATAL_ERROR "protobuf library is needed but cant be found")
#endif()
#find_package(gRPC REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm64)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin)
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES  arm64)

add_executable(grpc_test main.cpp svc.grpc.pb.cc svc.pb.cc)


include_directories(./ /usr/local/include)

target_link_libraries(grpc_test grpc++)
target_link_directories(grpc_test PUBLIC /usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.33.2_1/lib)
message(STATUS "archs is " ${CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES})
```

env:
protoc --verison: libprotoc 3.17.3
grep install by : brew install grep

I click clion build and get as error:

[ Build | grpc_test | Debug ]

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/jacke/CLionProjects/grpc_test --target grpc_test -- -j 6
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable grpc_test
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.33.2_1/lib/libgrpc++.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "grpc::ServerBuilder::BuildAndStart()", referenced from:
      RunServer() in main.cpp.o
  "grpc::ServerBuilder::RegisterService(grpc::Service*)", referenced from:
```

I has set CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR and CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES on CMakeLists.txt
but by this build debug info show that:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/jacke/CLionProjects/grpc_test --target grpc_test -- -j 6
```

CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR and CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES no work.
and I can not found them in Makefile who created by CMakeLists.txt

And How can I set link os setting in cmake ?

Comment: Setting variables `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` and `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES` is about **cross-compiling**, which is achieved in CMake by preparing a **separate** [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). Setting these variables **after** the `project` call doesn't work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know  variables CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR and CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES  is been used in cross-compiling, and cmake can create makefile BUT I can not found this two variables in makefile file any more. And clion toolchain https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-create-toolchain-in-clion.html I can not set variables any more .And can you set variables in toolchain file in mac  ?

Comment: Open cmake issue about correct detection for mismatched architectures: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22738